# Is there a way to time a "While" loop? (Python)

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I started teaching myself python a few days ago and today I was trying to make a `while` loop. However, it repeats itself very fast and I was looking for a way to slow it down.

```
def cursor():
    global cursors
    cursors += 1
    while 1 == 1:
        print("test")
```

I am using `print("test")` as a placeholder for what I need to be looped. It should print `'test'` then wait for a second or two and print the test again forever.

I would use a `for` loop but I don't know how to make it continue infinitely.

Comment: the keyword here is "delay". search "python delay" in google you'll get many resources like https://realpython.com/python-sleep/

Comment: FYI, you can do an infinite `for` loop with the `itertools` module: `for i in itertools.repeat(1):` but `while True:` is much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use `time.sleep()` within your loop. For example:

```
import time
def cursor():
    global cursors
    cursors += 1
    while 1 == 1:
        print("test")
        time.sleep(5)
```

Whereas the number in the brackets is the amount of seconds to pause your loop.

Answer (score 0):

The library `time` can be used to pause (in seconds)

```
import time
cursors = 0

def cursor():
    global cursors
    while True:
        cursors += 1
        print("test")
        time.sleep(1)    #pause 1 second
        if cursors == 10:    #break after 10 seconds
            break
```

You could also to specify another break condition to exit the loop